# PHP CURL use proxy to POST

Tags: php, post, curl, proxy

I'm trying to create a script that posts to an URL, using a list of proxies. The script seems to work fine without setting a proxy (CURLOPT_PROXY to null), but with a proxy set it does not seem to work. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? The error I'm getting when posting with a proxy is:

```
ERROR

The requested URL could not be retrieved

Invalid Request error was encountered while trying to process the request:

POST /###/ HTTP/1.1
Host: ###
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 368
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------9b24e849cac0
Some possible problems are:

Missing or unknown request method.

Missing URL.

Missing HTTP Identifier (HTTP/1.0).

Request is too large.

Content-Length missing for POST or PUT requests.

Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed.
```

And my code is:

```
$url = 'urltopost';
$proxy = 'proxy:port';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'postname1' => 'value1',
    'postname2' => 'value2'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the PROXYPORT option... You can't use the proxy:port notation

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,             "YOUR PROXY HOST");         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT,         "YOUR PROXY PORT");
```

Comment: Seems to be working now. Quite strange how the proxy:port notation did work when I did not add any POST variables though... but thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Hey, while I don't disagree with the solution, can you please explain why it won't work the other way? I can't find anywhere... and all the examples (along with PHP manual for curl_setopt()) put port and host together... Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, global env vars will also suffice?